# In first click google map info window not opening, its opening on second click only through ajax call, in V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am using below code to open up a infowindow in my map through ajax call

```
var openedInfoWindow = null; 
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function profileInitialiser(marker, location) {
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        new Ajax.Request('/ajax/', {
        parameters: {'action':'profileInfo', 'id':location.id},
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            addInfoWindow(marker, transport.responseText, location.id);
        }
    });
});
}

function addInfoWindow(marker, content, id) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    if (openedInfoWindow != null) {
        openedInfoWindow.close(); 
    } 
    infoWindow.setContent(content);
    infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    openedInfoWindow = infoWindow;  
    google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'closeclick', function() {
    openedInfoWindow = null;
    });
});
}
```

The above code, profileInitialiser function calling while loading on the marker in the google map. 
At fist time, first click on the marker through ajax call, the content of the infowindow comes as response.
In the second click the infowindow will open. Next time onwards, clicking on the marker loading the infowindow comes in first click. 
 Has any one had this bug before ? could some one help me to sort this issue please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your AddInfoWindow function just adds a click listener to the marker when the data comes back from the server.  You should also open the infoWindow with the content.

```
var openedInfoWindow = null; 
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function profileInitialiser(marker, location) {
// only do this on the first click
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(marker, 'click', function(){
        new Ajax.Request('/ajax/', {
        parameters: {'action':'profileInfo', 'id':location.id},
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            addInfoWindow(marker, transport.responseText, location.id);
        }
    });
});
}

function addInfoWindow(marker, content, id) {
  // display the content when the marker is clicked        
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    if (openedInfoWindow != null) {
        openedInfoWindow.close(); 
    } 
    infoWindow.setContent(content);
    infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    openedInfoWindow = infoWindow;  
    google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'closeclick', function() {
    openedInfoWindow = null;
    });
  });
  // click on the marker to display the newly added infowindow
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
}
```

Comment: I followed your code, but now clicking on the marker its continuously info window coming (triggering automatically). I wants, if i click on the marker in single click load the content through ajax and open the info window. Please suggest on this.

Comment: Did you make the modification in profileInitialiser from addListener to addListenerOnce?

Comment: That would explain the problem you reported, did making that change fix it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding click event listener twice. Just remove the listener from your addInfoWindow function.

Here is the code:

```
function addInfoWindow(marker, content, id) {

if (openedInfoWindow != null) {
    openedInfoWindow.close(); 
} 
infoWindow.setContent(content);
infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
openedInfoWindow = infoWindow;  
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'closeclick', function() {
openedInfoWindow = null;
});
}
```